# Printing map as several sheets of paper

Tags: qgis, scale, printing

I have a circular map (radius = 840m) and I need to print on A0 paper sheets. For references I am adding my qgis map and AutoCad model showing how it should be splitted into 20 A0 sheets.

[image: QGIS map I have to print out]

[image: AutoCad model shwoing required splitt]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: use the grid to power an atlas